# Scaling view depending on x coordinate while being dragged

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uipangesturerecognizer

I have been trying to implement a UI feature which I've seen in a few apps which use cards to display information. My current view controller looks like this:

[image]

and users are able to drag the card along the x axis to the left and right. Dragging to the right side of the screen does nothing to the scale of the card (simply changes position) but if the user swipes it to the left I wanted to slowly decrease the scale of it depending on its y coordinate (e.g. the scale is smallest when card is furthest to the left, getting bigger from that point until the original size is reached). If the card is dragged far enough to the left it will fade out, but if the user does not drag it far enough it increases in scale and moves back into the middle. Code I've tried so far:

```
- (void)handlePanImage:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    static CGPoint originalCenter;

    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    {
        originalCenter = sender.view.center;
        sender.view.alpha = 0.8;
        [sender.view.superview bringSubviewToFront:sender.view];
    }
    else if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
    {
        CGPoint translation = [sender translationInView:self.view];
        NSLog(@"%f x %f y",translation.x ,translation.y);
        sender.view.center=CGPointMake(originalCenter.x + translation.x, yOfView);
        CGAffineTransform transform = sender.view.transform;
        i-=0.001;
        transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, i, i);
        //transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, self.rotationAngle);
        sender.view.transform = transform;
    }
    else if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded || sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled || sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed)
    {
        if(sender.view.center.x>0){
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
                CGRect rect=[sender.view frame];
                rect.origin.x=([self.view frame].size.width/2)-_protoypeView.frame.size.width/2;
                rect.size.height=originalHeight;
                rect.size.width=originalWidth;
                [sender.view setFrame:rect];
                i=1.0;

            }];
        }
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1 animations:^{
            sender.view.alpha  = 1.0;
        }];
    }
}
```

This seems very buggy and doesn't properly work. I also tried to change scale according to translation:

```
else if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
    {
        CGPoint translation = [sender translationInView:self.view];
        NSLog(@"%f x %f y",translation.x ,translation.y);
        sender.view.center=CGPointMake(originalCenter.x + translation.x, yOfView);
        CGAffineTransform transform = sender.view.transform;
        transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, translation.x/100, translation.x/100);
        //transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, self.rotationAngle);
        sender.view.transform = transform;
    }
```

but the scale either gets too big or too small. Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the last piece of code you tried, you're doing a couple of things wrong. The scale transform will be cumulative because you never set the translation of your pan gesture recognizer back to 0. Also, if you look at the math in your transform, you'll see that a small movement of say -1 point would scale the view to 0.01 times its original size. You obviously don't want that. You need to add that small negative number to 1, so that initial -1 point move would scale to 0.99. The change of setting the panner's translation back to zero necessitates changing the center calculation to use sender.view.center.x rather than originalCenter.X. You also need an if statement to check whether the center is left or right of its starting position so you know whether you should apply the scaling transform. Something like this,

```
-(void)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *) sender {
    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        originalCenter = sender.view.center;
        sender.view.alpha = 0.8;
        [sender.view.superview bringSubviewToFront:sender.view];

    }else if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged){
        CGPoint translation = [sender translationInView:self.view];
        sender.view.center=CGPointMake(sender.view.center.x + translation.x, sender.view.center.y);
        if (sender.view.center.x < originalCenter.x) {
            CGAffineTransform transform = sender.view.transform;
            transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, 1+translation.x/100.0, 1+translation.x/100.0);
            sender.view.transform = transform;
        }
        [sender setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:self.view];
    }
}
```

This doesn't take care of animating the view back, or fading out the view, but it should get you most of the way there.

Comment: this works very well for the scale part of the view, but I can't seem to get it to return to its original size. Transforming scale to 1,1 has no effect and                                                                                           CGRect rect2=[sender.view frame];
        rect2.size.height=originalHeight;
        rect2.size.width=originalWidth;
        [sender.view setFrame:rect2];                             makes the view disappear overall when called in sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded.